# Calling Java method via a Mule Java component

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio

How do you specify the name of the function/method when calling a class using the Java component in Mule Anypoint-studio?

Answer (score 6):

I found out you have to setup a bean by adding the following to your mule configuration xml file.

```
   <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean name="myBean" class="MyClass"/>
    </spring:beans>
```

then use the Invoke component where you can specify the bean and the function/method you wish to call

```
 <invoke name="aName" object-ref="myBean" method="raiseException" doc:name="Invoke"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java Component, then you can try this directly into Configuration XML:

```
<component class="com.mulesoft.training.JavaWithMultipleMethods" doc:name="Java">
    <method-entry-point-resolver>
        <include-entry-point method="getMethod"/>
    </method-entry-point-resolver>
</component>
```